# why can't I retrieve the comment ID?

Tags: comments

I wrote a function to update the comment time when a comment goes form unapproved to approved:

```
function ji_update_comment_date($comment){
$commentarr = array(
                'comment_ID'=>comment_ID(),
                //this is where it fails me,I can't get the ID
                'comment_date'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                'comment_date_gmt'=> date("Y-m-d H:i:s") 
                );

        wp_update_comment( $commentarr );}
add_action('comment_unapproved_to_approved','ji_update_comment_date');
```

SO the comment_ID() is not working ,I can't seem to get it otherwise my code works perfectly.

Comment: Hi, Have you tried `get_comment_ID()` instead because `comment_ID()` must be within a loop.

Comment: yeah,I tried ,it's not working neither.

Comment: I was reading a post a while back, and someone mentioned that you have to get the comment using `$comment = get_comment( $comment );` first.

Comment: thank you ,but still it's not working.I tried $comment = get_comment( $comment );,'comment_ID'=>$comment->ID,

Comment: you are welcome. you should put the line before `$commentarr` tho, not before `comment_iD`.

Comment: yes,I put it before the $commentarr array.It's not woring.I think get_comment() itself needs a comment ID to work.

Comment: Oddly enough, `get_comment_ID()` worked for me with JS disabled. Using the suggestion from @JackJohansson ( adding `$comment = get_comment( $comment );` see http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/45195/2807 ) and using `'comment_ID' => $comment->comment_ID,` ended up being the real solution.

Comment: @DaveRomsey yes, i'm wondering why it's not working in his case. There might be a function or code before it, changing the results since `$comment->comment_ID` should absolutely work.

Comment: Thank you guys ,it works now ,thank you for the clarity @Dave Romsey,it should be  'comment_ID' => $comment->comment_ID instead of what I used 'comment_ID'=>$comment->ID.Thank you for the get_comment tip Jack Johansson.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So @Jack Johansson and @Dave Romsey helped me to make it work.So I will put the solution here:

```
function ji_update_comment_date($comment,$commentarr){

$comment = get_comment( $comment );
$commentarr = array(
                'comment_ID'=>$comment->comment_ID,
                'comment_date'=>date("Y-m-d H:i:s"),
                'comment_date_gmt'=> date("Y-m-d H:i:s") 
                );

        wp_update_comment( $commentarr         );}
add_action('comment_unapproved_to_approved','ji_update_comment_date');
```

I don't understand why comment_ID() and get_comment_ID() won't work in this scenario. But get_comment is surely a workaround.